# Eclipse in Linux: running a Junit coverage test gives an error "permission denied"

Tags: linux, eclipse, junit, code-coverage, permission-denied

I am getting a `java.io.IOException: Permission Denied` error when I try to run a Coverage test over my Java project.

I can run individual JUnit tests, and they work fine.

Running the tests all together (via Coverage as JUnit tests), I get the error.

The Plug-in related to the error is `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core`.

The stack trace given starts with `org.eclipse.core.internals.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)` and ends with `java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)`.

I was able to run the coverage test before I built my project, but after the build it will not run. Not sure if these are connected.

Comment: Include the entire stacktrace.

Comment: The issue is fixed now (see my answer below), so I don't have the error anymore (can't get the stack trace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - `java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)`. One of my tests (the newest one, which had not yet run under the Coverage test) was trying to write to a file that somehow had the permissions changed. Once the permissions were reset to allow me access, the Coverage test runs. Still not sure why it allowed me to individually run the test, but it all runs now.